# Bootstrap cards not working in bootstrapemail

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I have a nice web page built up with cards but they simply dont seem to work when i paste it in the editor in the bootstrapemail editor which returns pure css code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Vrindavan Chandrodaya Mandir</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="LayoutIt!">
    <!--Template based on URL below-->
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/starter-template/">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <!--    <link href="css/Bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
</head>

<body class="" style="background-color: azure">

  <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card bg-primary">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the first card</p>
      <div class="card-footer">Hare Krishna</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-warning">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the second card</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-success">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the third card</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-danger">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the fourth card</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
        ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body></html>
```

I am using https://bootstrapemail.com/editor to get pure css to make some nice emails. Where am I going wrong? I know only bootstrap as my go to platform for designing.

Comment: don't use that type of mailer, make your email using pure flexbox, it less your code and you can edit your css without any fear

Comment: acha i will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through your `code and with bootstrap email` and I found that you missed some divs like `container` . You didn't mentioned 
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">` as they did.

```
//Here is a sample

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-mailer-dbc5154d3c4160e8fa7ef52fa740fa402760c39b5d22c8f6d64ad5999499d263.css" />
   <style><!-- Add custom styles that you want inlined here --></style>
 </head>

<body class="bg-light">
<preview>Thank you for riding with Lyft!</preview>
<div class="container">
  <img class="mx-auto mt-4 mb-3" width="42" height="30" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/lyft.zimride.com/images/emails/logo/v2/logo_44@2x.png" />
   <div class="card mb-4" style="border-top: 5px solid #ff00bf;">
  <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card bg-primary">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the first card</p>
      <div class="card-footer">Hare Krishna</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-warning">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the second card</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-success">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the third card</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card bg-danger">
    <div class="card-body text-center">
      <p class="card-text">Some text inside the fourth card</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

//result

[image]